# What properties are in Jenkins / Hudson available for build configuration?

Tags: build, properties, hudson, jenkins, continuous-integration

The question is in the title

I know about `BUILD_NAME` and `BUILD_ID` and `BUILD_TAG` and I have seen somewhere a list of properties, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is

- a quite [extensive list in the JENKINS wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-below) (or if you prefer in the [Hudson Wiki](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-HudsonSetEnvironmentVariables),
- there is a link to it below the textarea where you specify your build steps (see below)
- you could run `env` as bash script in a build step to find out which additional variables are inherited on your system:

[image]

Comment: Execute shell helped in my case since I was looking for a custom env variable. Thanks so much

Comment: Alternatively use `SET` in a windows batch command for the same result.

Comment: in a groovy script, what are the properties available for "currentBuild" object?

Answer (score 13):

To view available env vars in your case (since they also depend on installed plugins) just go to this URL:

`https://<your-jenkins>/env-vars.html`

Replace `https://<your-jenkins>/` with how you used to access your Jenkins (it can be, just for instance
`http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html`
or
`https://linux-jenkins-1:8443/env-vars.html`).

Answer (score 3):

Updating the link to Jenkins WIKI: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-below

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables